# How to jump to next chapter when playing back videos?

Tags: video

I'm trying to play back .mp4 videos that have chapters embedded in them. They play fine on desktop players like VLC, and on my iPod, but I can't select/choose/jump to these chapter markers on Android.  What am I missing?

Comment: What video player are you using? If it's one that came with your phone, you'll also need to tell us what phone you have.

Comment: There is VLC for Android available at F-Droid.

Comment: VLC is available at Google Play.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely because the player app you are using is not aware of the embedded chapters.  I recommend searching Google Play Store for video player apps that support this feature.

A quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=android%20video%20player%20chapters) points to [Simple Cinema](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devrev.simplecinema) and [XBMC](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Android) (not on Google Play).  I have not tried these personally, but this should start you off in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use VLC for Android.   :)